# Why was gerund not using in this sentence as parallel balance?

Tags: grammar, gerunds, gerunds-vs-participles

In the following sentence, why the author uses 'stole' and 'stood' instead of 'stealing' and 'standing', since the author use 'seeing' the gerund at the second clause.

> An elderly seaman came to the gate and paused irresolute, then **seeing** all was quiet, **stole** cautiously on to the jetty, and **stood** for some time gazing curiously down on the deck of the billyboy Mary Ann lying alongside.

Comment: They match with “came” and “paused”.   “Seeing” is the odd man out here.

Comment: *Seeing* is not part of the parallel thing. Because of X, he did Y and Z. So, there's no need for matching X-Y-Z.

Comment: Cannot actually see the question.